# SysJobHistory run_duration to DD:HH:MM:SS

Tags: t-sql

Im trying to convert time from SysJobsHistory run_duration seconds to show Days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
SELECT
STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(jh.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') as 'StepLastRunDuration',
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh
```

I have one outcome which is 00:25:30:18 (25hr, 30min, 18sec) however I want it to show 01:01:30:18 (1day, 1hr, 30min, 18sec)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(
    RIGHT('00' + TRIM(STR((jh.run_duration / 240000))), 2) +
    RIGHT('00' + TRIM(STR((jh.run_duration / 10000) % 24)), 2) +
    RIGHT('0000' + STR(jh.run_duration), 4)
    , 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') AS 'StepLastRunDuration'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh
```